# android onTouchEvent is not working

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I want to scroll the page when the method sendScroll() called. The scrolling is working and i want to stop the scrolling when touching on the screen. In the below code the on touchevent is not working.

```
private void sendScroll(){
    final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0,5);         // 5 is how many pixels you want it to scroll vertically by
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);     // 10 is how many milliseconds you want this thread to run

        }


        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // MotionEvent object holds X-Y values
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //String text = "You click at x = " + event.getX() + " and y = " + event.getY();
                //Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable); //stop
            }

            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

    };
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);//start


}
```

It shows error on timerRunnable and onTouchEvent(event).

Comment: Link the exact error.

Comment: `timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable)` How can you remove `timerRunnable` when you're inside it?

Comment: Why did you write onTouchEvent inside send scroll method?

Comment: @Danieboy The error is "Variable timerRunnable might not have been initialized".

Comment: @Zar how did i stop the scrolling when i touch the button.

Comment: @Jai I have wrote onTouchEvent in outside the sendscroll method but it is not working.

Comment: @faziltm : Remove the condition "if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)" and call directly timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);

Comment: @faziltm : Also ovverride onTouchEvent outside the sendScroll method

Comment: @jai Removing if condition it shows the same error. When override on touchevent outside the it shows the error.